# DataFrame: как обратиться к элементу списка в ячейке

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу обратиться к элементу списка внутри dataframe?
У меня есть следующий код:

```
import pandas as pd
dict = {'Name': [['Martha', 'A1'], ['Tim', 'A1'],
                ['Rob', 'A1'], ['Georgia', 'A1']],
         'Marks': [87, 91, 
                  97, 95]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
print(df.values[0]) # Я пробовал сделать df.values[0][1] - но так не работает
```

Выводит следующее:
[list(['Martha', 'A1']) 87]
А мне нужно
['A1', 87]
Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно осуществить? Буду очень сильно благодарен за помощь

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К элементу списка в значении в датафрейме можно обратиться через аксессор `str`:

```
import pandas as pd
dict = {'Name': [['Martha', 'A1'], ['Tim', 'A1'],
                ['Rob', 'A1'], ['Georgia', 'A1']],
         'Marks': [87, 91, 
                  97, 95]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
print(df["Name"].str[1])
```

```
0    A1
1    A1
2    A1
3    A1
```

Comment: Спасибо большущее!